# Is there any way to recover the deleted profile in sandbox

Tags: profile

I want to know is there any way to recover the deleted profile in sandbox.

Thanks,
Suri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike records, profiles are part of the metadata, therefore they are not stored in the Recycle Bin.You may be able to recover via customer support.  I'm not certain of that.

Tip:  Every so often, use the Metadata API to download your org's source and related metadata.  Reference and tutorial links:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunitely, you cannot recover deleted [profile](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_userprofiles.htm&language=en) as its not moved to recycle bin.

Nearest I can think of, you can see [Audit trail](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=admin_monitorsetup.htm&siteLang=en_US) to see which profiles were deleted in last 180 days and recreate it again.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is that if you have deployed change sets that haven´t expired with the metadata that you want, you can redeploy the change set. This will restore the metadata

Answer (score -1):

If the profile exists in Production, a refresh will restore it.

Other than that, there is no way to do this - you could raise a case with support to see if they can do anything for you.